# How to get bash output over ssh via Paramiko

Tags: python, bash, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to test file permissions of a user prior to performing some other commands via ssh. I have:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
channel = ssh.get_transport().open_session()

# Check permissions
channel.send("if [ -w %s ]; then echo \"true\"; else echo \"false\"; fi\n" % self.dest_path)
    if (channel.recv(1024) == "false"):
        exit(PRIV_ERR)
```

However, I never get a response from the remote machine. Other `.recv()` calls work fine, with response, so I'm thinking there's an issue with my bash script? It works fine locally. I get a timeout exception when I try to receive over the ssh channel though.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with sending paths and/or running small scripts -- it's easy to not quote things correctly. This will show up as the program running correctly most of the time, but failing to handle files with spaces, or apostrophes, or Unicode characters.

This code runs "test -f (mypath)" remotely, signaling if `mypath` is a file or not.  Consider using a more sophisticated library like Fabric for this kind of thing -- it's more reliable.  ([Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) link)

### source

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('localhost')

# Check permissions
# TODO: do proper quoting to handle filenames with apostrophes
_stdin,stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command(
    "test -f '{}' && echo isfile".format('/etc/issue')
)
isfile = stdout.read().strip() == 'isfile'
print 'isfile:', isfile
```

### output

```
isfile: True
```